# How to copy innertext from a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, copy, copy-paste

I have a contenteditable div whose initial content is set at runtime on the server side.  The user then needs to be able to make edits on the client side (thus contenteditable).  The user then needs to be able to copy the edited contents of txtDiv with a copy button.

I have tried the code below, but I need for it to work on txtDiv not myInput.  Also, it does not work on myInput if I add runat="server" to myInput.

This works as expected:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied");
}
</script>
    <!-- The text field -->
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">


<!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

I need this to work:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("txtDiv").innertext;

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied");
}
</script>
    <!-- The text field -->
    <div id="TxtDiv" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" aria-multiline="True" contenteditable="true" 
        style="z-index: 1; text-align:left; border:1px solid; overflow-y:scroll; height: 82px"></div>

<!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

The user then needs to be able to copy the editted contents of txtDiv with a copy button.

Comment: Why did you put ```runat="server" ``` on the ```div```?

Comment: Because the innertext of the div comes from a variable that is set on the server as a result of user input.  It is not just simple user input that could be handled on the client side.  The code behind actually manipulates user input to derive the output that ultimately is displayed.

Comment: Did you only need to copy text of the div or all in the div (tag, new line, etc)?

Comment: I just need the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial answer at https://forums.asp.net/t/2157977.aspx?How+to+copy+innertext+from+a+contenteditable+div+whose+initial+value+is+set+on+the+server+side+ provided by @Wei got me 90% of the way to the answer. The only thing that I would add is two things: 1) Hyphens are not allowed in control names in the code behind so "my-div" cannot be used if you want to access that control from the code behind.  2)The div needs to be on the client side and you cannot set the innerhtml property from the code behind since the control is not on the server.  To get around this I put a span and a server literal into the innerhtml of the div.  Now I can set the text of the literal using html constructed in the code behind and it results in the desired output in the div.

The final code that works is:

```
<script>
  function copy() {
      var target = document.getElementById('mydiv');
      var range, select;
      if (document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(target)
        select = window.getSelection();
        select.removeAllRanges();
        select.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        select.removeAllRanges();
      } else {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(target);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
      }
    }
</script>

<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true" style="z-index: 1; text-align:left; border:1px solid; overflow-y:scroll; height: 82px"><span><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span></div>

<div><input onclick="copy()" type="button" value="Copy" /></div>
```

And the code behind is:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Literal1.text="<span style='color:#d9534f'> Red </span><span style='color:#0275d8'> Blue </span>"

    End Sub
```

Not only will this allow you to copy the contents of the div but you can have several different colors of text in the div and you can also edit the contents of the div and the edited version will be copied.